# Apply new function on an object

Tags: java

I have a string, and I want to do a bunch of things on it at once (it will be a bunch of replacements) in a function.  I want to do something to the degree of `string.color()` if the string is called `string` and the function I make is `color()`.  How should I declare `color()`?  Should I do it in a class extending `String` or an interface?  Should I just give that up and do `color(string)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String is a final class in java and so you cannot extend and add method to String class
 You **should** do `color(String)` instead. 
If you're dealing with bunch of replacement in String consider [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just do `public String color(String) { ... }`.

Since you can't change a `String` (i.e. they're immutable), you're going to end up returning a new `String` from either approach. Might as well take the more straightforward one until circumstances justify using something more complex like inheritance or composition.

Comment: True, but since in my code, `string` is really something more like `something.aFunction().anotherFunction()`, it would look better if I could just add a `.color()` instead of putting it all in the function :P.

Comment: Are you specifically looking to make a fluent interface like that? If so, I would recommend updating your question to state that.

Comment: Also, what are `aFunction()` and `anotherFunction()`? Are those methods that are already defined for `String`, or are they your own methods as well?

Comment: I thought I made it clear I was trying to get that to work, but it sounds like it won't work.  As for the functions, they are actually functions from a variable given by the program I'm writing a plugin for, and don't have any control over :P.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note - neither of your suggestions (class extending `String`, or an interface) would let you avoid `color(String)`:

- `String` is a final class, so you can't define a subclass of it with your own operations on.
- You can create any interfaces you like, but you can't make `String` implement them - so the method on the interface would need to take a String as an argument, and then you're back to `color(String)` again.

Answer (score 1):

Consider composition (e.g. a simple wrapper for `String`):

```
public class EnhancedString {
    private String str;
    public EnhancedString(final String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
    public EnhancedString color() {
        // do some stuff and return the result
        return this;
    }
    public EnhancedString anotherReplacement() {
        // more stuff
        return this;
    }
}
```

What's nice about this approach is that it allows you to chain method invocations later (jQuery-style):

```
EnhancedString estr = new EnhancedString("testing");
estr.color().anotherReplacement();
```

Comment: +1, The question isn't quite clear, but I think this is what the asker is after (some sort of String formatter/prettifier fluent interface).

Answer (score 0):

String is **final** so you can't extend it.

Just do color(String).

Answer (score 0):

String is final and immutable so you will not be able to extend it and make a subclass that has new methods on it such as color.

One approach is to create a StringUtil class that has the method color defined, i.e.

```
public static String color(String someString) {
    // Your logic that creates a new "colored" String and returns this new String
}
```

You can then just call:

```
String coloredString = StringUtil.color(someString);
```

As an aside, every time you perform any operation on a String a new String object is returned so it is more efficient to use something like a StringBuilder if you are performing many operations (such as concatenation) on the String in your color method and the you can just return the result of the StringBuilder's toString() method.